# expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token error

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, ubuntu-17.04

I'm using ubuntu 17.04 LTS alongside gcc 7.3 alognside CMake. Unfortunately, I'm getting this error:

```
[ 37%] Building CXX object source/server/Scripts/CMakeFiles/L5RP.dir/CarDealer/cardealer.cpp.o
/home/kkraujelis/Desktop/L5RP/ragemp/source/server/Scripts/CarDealer/cardealer.cpp:10:30: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
 CarDealer::CarOffer::CarOffer(CarDealer::CarDealer const* dealer, uint32_t price, std::string const& model, double fuelUsagePerKilo) {
                              ^
source/server/Scripts/CMakeFiles/L5RP.dir/build.make:182: recipe for target 'source/server/Scripts/CMakeFiles/L5RP.dir/CarDealer/cardealer.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [source/server/Scripts/CMakeFiles/L5RP.dir/CarDealer/cardealer.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:194: recipe for target 'source/server/Scripts/CMakeFiles/L5RP.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [source/server/Scripts/CMakeFiles/L5RP.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Everywhere I read up about it it turned out to be basic syntax error or a lot of other things. Probably I'm blind, however everytime I checked on the code it seemed allright.

Header:

```
#pragma once

#define SIMEONS_CARDEALER   0

namespace L5RP {

    namespace Scripts {

        namespace CarDealer {

            class CarDealer;
            class CarDealerScript;

            class CarOffer {

                CarDealer const* dealer;
                uint32_t price;
                std::string model;
                double fuelUsagePerKilo;

            public:

                CarOffer(
                    CarDealer const* dealer,
                    uint32_t price,
                    std::string const& model,
                    double fuelUsagePerKilo
                );

                CarDealer const* getDealer() const;
                uint32_t getPrice() const;
                std::string const& getModelName() const;
                uint32_t getModel() const;
                double getFuelUsagePerKilo() const;

            };

            /*** Some other classes ***/

        }

    }

}

#include "Simeons/simeons.h"
```

Source:

```
#include "../scripts.h"

using namespace L5RP;
using namespace L5RP::Scripts;
using namespace L5RP::Scripts::Government;
using namespace L5RP::Scripts::CarDealer;
using namespace L5RP::Scripts::Character;
using namespace L5RP::Scripts::VehicleLogic;

CarDealer::CarOffer::CarOffer(CarDealer::CarDealer const* dealer, uint32_t price, std::string const& model, double fuelUsagePerKilo) {
    this->dealer = dealer;
    this->price = price;
    this->model = model;
    this->fuelUsagePerKilo = fuelUsagePerKilo;
}
```

Comment: You use two same names `CarDealer` for class and namespace. If you state using the namespace then you don't need to prefix class members definitions with the namespace.

Comment: I've used it before and it turned out allright. However I'll try to change name of the class.

Comment: What was working before probably was not identical to today's code.

Comment: Yeah the name change fixed the problem. However, what name would you recommend for me if I have CarDealer namespace and I want to define CarDealer class inside of it? I mean I can't have class without a name.

Comment: Maybe name classes in the namespace without beginning Car: Dealer, Offer.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that would do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem was fixed in the comment section by https://stackoverflow.com/users/6752050/s-m.

I can't mark his comment as answer. So I will quote him:

> You use two same names CarDealer for class and namespace. If you state using the namespace then you don't need to prefix class members definitions with the namespace.

Comment: @S.M, you've been quoted for "your" answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you implement your function, you have to fully qualify the class type including namespaces.

Usually you would simply surround you definition with appropriate namespaces as in:

```
namespace L5RP {
    namespace Scripts {
        namespace CarDealer {
            CarOffer::CarOffer(CarDealer const* dealer, uint32_t price, std::string const& model, double fuelUsagePerKilo) 
            {
                this->dealer = dealer;
                this->price = price;
                this->model = model;
                this->fuelUsagePerKilo = fuelUsagePerKilo;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even better, you would initialize your members in the initialization list whenever appropriate. So your code would look like:

```
namespace L5RP 
{
    namespace Scripts 
    {
        namespace CarDealer 
        {
            CarOffer::CarOffer(CarDealer const* dealer, uint32_t price, std::string const& model, double fuelUsagePerKilo) 
                : dealer(dealer)
                , price(price)
                , model(model)
                , fuelUsagePerKilo(fuelUsagePerKilo)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't first example do what my using namespace L5RP;
using namespace L5RP::Scripts; did? Also sometimes compiler has forced me to initialize stuff like you did. What it does change?

Comment: Well, using the initialization list avoid redundant initialization (here default construction and then assignment). Expert C++ programmer usually write efficient code.

Comment: I have never seen or tried to use namespace for defining stuff in them. I never expect that it would have works and never seen any example where it was done.